# Document Clustering for given specific clusters in python

Tags: python, nlp, clustering, data-analysis

How can we classify text in to given specific number of clusters in python? I'm aware that the number of clusters can be specified using some mechanisms like k-means but I need to classify the given to specific categories.

Ex: I'm having a corpus containing newspaper articles and I want to cluster them pertaining to sports, foreign and local.

Is there anyway to achieve this in python? I've googled but could not find a good match.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

So, Clustering is "Unsupervised" learning : You make groups in which elements look like each-other. In Unsupervised learning, you don't have a Label that you look for.

Here, your problem is to Classify text between 3 categories : Sports, Foreign, Local.
Those 3 categories ARE labels : You know you have news about those 3 subjects, and want to make a model that learns characteristics of those 3 categories to automatically assign a label to a new unknown article : This is called Classification, which is Supervised learning.
Since you have more than 2 labels (classification is usually Yes or No), you're in a
"Multi Label Text Classification Problem".
If you're starting in Data Science, that's a really tough subject, far from easy.